# File Download in mvc 4 is not working, no errors but file not downloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, download

File content result in mvc , no errors but file not downloading , can anyone find the issue  pls...

```
public FileContentResult download(string data)
{
    StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    DataTable tblTemp = new DataTable();
    MyStringBuilder.Append("select up.file_upload_pk,up.filename,up.contenttype,up.bytes from xxx up where up.yyy='xx'");
    SAPDashboard.dl.clsDb objDB = new SAPDashboard.dl.clsDb(dl.clsDb.connection.Dashboard);
    tblTemp = objDB.getTable(MyStringBuilder.ToString());
    byte[] bytes=null;
    string fileName= string.Empty;
    string contentType=string.Empty;
    string datas = tblTemp.Rows[0]["bytes"].ToString();
    bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(datas);
    byte[] byteArray = bytes;
    contentType = Convert.ToString(tblTemp.Rows[0]["contenttype"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : tblTemp.Rows[i]["contenttype"]);
    fileName = Convert.ToString(tblTemp.Rows[0]["filename"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : tblTemp.Rows[i]["filename"]);
    return  File(bytes, contentType,fileName);
}
```

output parameter value

```
bytes=  {byte[117808]},
contentType=  "application/pdf",
fileName=  "PaySlip636269030754635548.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved FileDownloads by implementing something similar to the simplified following code, hope it helps.

**View**

```
@model List<string>
<h2>Downloads</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count-1; i++)

    {

        <tr>
            <td>@Model[i].ToString() </td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", 
            "Download", new { ImageName = @Model[i].ToString() }) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Downloads()
        {
            var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/"));
            System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dir.GetFiles("*.*"); List<string> items = new List<string>();
            foreach (var file in fileNames)
            {
                items.Add(file.Name);
            }
            return View(items);
        }

        public FileResult Download(string ImageName)
        {
            var FileVirtualPath = "~/App_Data/uploads/" + ImageName;
            return File(FileVirtualPath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(FileVirtualPath));
        }
```

Comment: And you don't have to do anything with javascript in order to get the download? Nothing downloads for me. no errors or anything.